# iPhone application needs to authenticate with Joomla using ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, ios, joomla, asihttprequest

I am writing an iPhone application to connect with a website running Joomla (JomSocial to be exact) and retrieve certain information from it.
Where I'm totally stuck these last days is to the authentication process.
I'm not a web/php expert (just knowing the basics) and developing in combination with the Joomla platform for the first time.

The scenario is: There is a website with a login form (username/password/remember) in which a user logs in. 
On the iPhone, the user starts the app and is presented with a typical signin view containing two UITextFields, one for the username and one for the password. There's also a button to proceed with the authentication and call the method posted below.
When the user fills the required fields, the app assumes remember button and proceeds with the authentication where it stays authenticated until a logout button is pressed.

To do that, I am implementing the ASIHTTPRequest API to send the information on the website. The code for the authentication method follows:

```
- (void)performAuthentication
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebsite.com/index.php?option=com_community"];

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDelegate:self];

    [request setUseKeychainPersistence:YES];
    [request setUseCookiePersistence:YES];
    [request setUseSessionPersistence:YES];
    [request setShouldAttemptPersistentConnection:YES];

    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setUserAgent:@"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A405 Safari/7534.48.3"]; //does not matter, I was just trying it
    [request setTimeOutSeconds:20];

    //main login options - user fills in 
    [request setPostValue:emailText.text forKey:@"username"];
    [request setPostValue:passwordText.text forKey:@"passwd"];
    [request setPostValue:@"yes" forKey:@"remember"];

    //secondary options derived from string
    [request setPostValue:@"Log+in" forKey:@"submit"];
    [request setPostValue:@"com_user" forKey:@"option"];
    [request setPostValue:@"login" forKey:@"task"];

    [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{   
    NSLog(@"STATUS CODE: %i", [request responseStatusCode]);
    NSLog(@"STATUS MESSAGE: %@", [request responseStatusMessage]);
    NSLog(@"HEADERS: %@", [request responseHeaders]);
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
}
```

the results from the requestFinished are:

```
2012-01-18 17:15:48.850 MyApp[3500:f803] STATUS CODE: 200
2012-01-18 17:15:48.850 MyApp[3500:f803] STATUS MESSAGE: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2012-01-18 17:15:48.851 MyApp[3500:f803] HEADERS: 
{
    "Cache-Control" = "post-check=0, pre-check=0";
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Wed, 18 Jan 2012 15:15:51 GMT";
    Expires = "Mon, 1 Jan 2001 00:00:00 GMT";
    "Last-Modified" = "Wed, 18 Jan 2012 15:15:51 GMT";
    P3P = "CP=\"NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM\"";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = "Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 mod_perl/2.0.5 Perl/v5.10.1";
    "Set-Cookie" = "currentURI=http%3A%2F%mywebsite.com%2Findex.php%3Foption%3Dcom_community; expires=Thu, 19-Jan-2012 15:15:51 GMT; path=/";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.2.17";
}
```

When using Firefox with the livehttpheaders addon, I get this:

```
POST /index.php?option=com_community HTTP/1.1
Host: mywebsite.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://mywebsite.com/index.php
Cookie: referrerid=AUPRR-4F16C6005781D; currentURI=http%3A%2F%2Fmywebsite.com%2Findex.php; 5ddfdbeb767d245c52d97fea9c4ba768=92a78d2faee8e9029d29d56d5d5270dc; activeProfile=90
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 256
username=my_user&passwd=my_pass&submit=log+in&option=com_user&task=login&return=L2luZGV4LnBocD9vcHRpb249Y29tX2NvbW11bml0eSZ2aWV3PWZyb250cGFnZSZJdGVtaWQ9MzM%3D&3946e5e25450d1a242ceffbd96ea8733=1&remember=yes

HTTP/1.1 303 See other
Date: Wed, 18 Jan 2012 13:29:13 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 mod_perl/2.0.5 Perl/v5.10.1
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"
Set-Cookie: 5ddfdbeb767d245c52d97fea9c4ba768=bff8a2f942f8e23633a8816cd36de1cb; path=/
Set-Cookie: activeProfile=90; expires=Wed, 18-Jan-2012 13:44:13 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: afcee664c0a8fd2cd6ff5cc9df8eab30=51+9+2+218475F+A+216444A5C165F505456145D115F535B+31011+74350+25455405D78+459+45B541A52565446+A42+3+B+C4412+411114E5D13+613+212+2+7+912+951+715+2+1+C13+244; expires=Thu, 17-Jan-2013 13:29:13 GMT; path=/
Location: http://mywebsite.com/index.php?option=com_community
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

I'm facing 3 problems:

1. I'm getting a 200 response code instead of a 303 the livehttpheaders indicate.
2. the cookie named activeProfile does not appear to be saved on the cookie storage.
3. the long token on the Content-Length response (as shown in livehttpheader output) cannot be used as it is random on each authentication and I don't know what to do with it.

In general it seems that the authentication method connects but does not perform the process and what remains are the cookies of the standard http access. I can verify this by loading a UIWebView with the website address and I see that the user is not logged in.

I'm not a web expert (although I can understand certain things) and working with Joomla authentication for the first time.
I am just wondering if anyone has faced something similar and has found a way through.
Any idea or advice is much much appreciated.

thanx ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed you are not setting any HttpHeaders in your code.  Check your HttpHeaders which should match to Joomla headers.

Comment: Yes I tried that. Added all headers related sent but still no authentication.